# Can playwright check for an element with a custom name?

Tags: angular, typescript, playwright

I'm working on an angular/typescript application where our pages utilize elements that just bring up other pages. For example the date-time element is just for how we display date and time data.

In playwright, I've seen example code along the lines of

`await expect(page.locator('date-time').isVisible);`

with different selectors and filters attached, but is there a way that instead of div I could have it expect to contain date-time?

Edit: Just in case it helps, here's an example of the html of the element I'm looking for:
`<date-time> [start]='startTime' [end]='endTime' [date]='date' </date-time>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the text locator and then the visible expect assertion for this something like:

```js
expect('text=06 Jul 2022').toBeVisible()
```

You can check for the `date-time` tag visible on dom,

```js
await expect(page.locator('date-time')).toBeVisible()
```

You if you just want to check that the element exist in DOM, you can do:

```js
await expect(page.locator('date-time').count()).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make it vague? Like I don't want to have to test what the element contains, just that it's loading.

Comment: Please add the HTML of the element and please explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: ```<date-time>
[start]='startTime'
[end]='endTime'
[date]='date'
</date-time>```